# What do the Muton abilities do?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Mutons are large green troops that tend to carry plasma rifles and grenades.  Often I see them use two abilities.  Intimidate and Blood Call.

**What are the effects of Intimidate and Blood Call?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Intimidate causes your soldiers to have a chance to panic.  It is a trigger reaction only if it takes damage from a shot (but not killed).

And from what I can tell, blood call increases nearby Muton's effectiveness by increasing (Thanks to Raven Dreamer for the right stats):
 - Aim
 - Will
 - Movement Distance

[image]

Comment: Also, the Berserker's Intimidate causes him to move closer to whoever shot him.